# Split mesh of trees into many parts

Tags: mesh

I have a landscape full of trees which I need to split up before it's able to be imported into a game. The game has a vertex limit for each object at 65k, so I'll need to cut my trees object into over 100 pieces for them to fit.

Is there a way to split it using a grid, or some automated method like that?

Thanks, I've been struggling with this for months already, it's very tedious and time consuming to split the mesh over and over every time I make an edit to the landscape/tree placement.

[image: Many trees]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8870/599 and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3619/599