# how to bake high poly and texture normal map together

Tags: normals

okay so. my plan is to add a normal map and texture to a low poly mesh. the normal map should be a combination of the high poly model and a texture. they should be baked together. I know you can bake them separately but that's not what I need. I need them together. could you please help? I think I figured it out but the mesh cant connect to itself or everything is messed up. ex) it will work on a plane but not on a cube. please help and thank you for doing so. :)

Comment: A normal map and a color texture contain different kinds of information. You can combine them, but it will make a pretty useless texture in most cases.. Are you sure this is what you want to do? Usually the color texture and the normal map are applied separately, as separate textures.

Answer (score 1):

See [How does normal baking work?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-does-normal-baking-work) on how normal maps are created.

You can't bake other textures and the normal into a normal map because the normal map encodes the direction of the normals in the RGB channels of the image representing the map.

From [Bump_and_Normal](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Bump_and_Normal)  (Linked to 2.4 because there is more info)

> Normal maps in Blender store a normal as follows:
>
> - Red maps from (0-255) to X (-1.0 - 1.0)
> - Green maps from (0-255) to Y (-1.0 - 1.0)
> - Blue maps from (0-255) to Z (0.0 - 1.0)

Since can add more than one texture to a model this isn't a restriction.

EDIT: A normal vector is perpendicular to a face its coordinates (x,y,z) are stored as a pixel in an image map.

[image]

Comment: im sorry. im a little confused. can you explain some please? :) thank you for trying to answer though. so. how do video games have normal maps? in video games it looks like they have a high poly normal map and then a texture normal map combined and then applied to a low poly mesh so you have say, smooth surface on a cube but then rocky normal map on the curved surface too.

Comment: like if you have a rope with 3 sides but it looks round because of the normal map but then you might have a tear in it so they add the normal map of the tear into it too. if  im making any sense

Comment: @EthanSmith I added an image to explain it a bit more. Could you give a reference for a game engine. If you have a low poly model like your rope example you would need additional information (from a high poly rope) to add fake geometry to the rendering. Interpolating the normals of a 3-sided rope couldn't do that.

Comment: okay. so those lines are perpendicular to the faces theyre protruding from? I think that's what you mean. so then. if I were to bake a normal map of the mesh it would look.... like the mesh... but then if I change the.... "blue" or the "Z"... I could also get the texture applied to the mesh into the normal map? is that what youre saying? and then say what I just said works... I could then apply the combined mesh and texture normal to a low poly mesh to have a more detailed low poly mesh look high poly with a texture normal?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " get the **texture** applied to the mesh into the normal map?" Have you already read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-does-normal-baking-work ?

Comment: the game engine would be Unity3d and your example would be, I have a rock im modeling. there are two versions, a low poly of 500 polygons and a high of 2000. I also have a high res texture for my rock. if I generate a normal (or bump ive read what the difference is but im not sure which is best, but my guess would be normals are still better) from the high res rock and apply it to the low res rock it then looks like the high res rock now. but then. I have my texture which I have just generated a normal for. I cant have two normal, so how would I merge them or bake them together?

Comment: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-bumpmap.html

Comment: I read that. I understand it too. so let me try again. y'know how you can make a normal from a texture right? and.. also from a mesh. I want to apply a texture to a mesh and have it generate the texture normal into the mesh normal so instead of having two normal I have one combined normal. is that clear enough? (no sarcasm or rudness intended) the unity thing looked like it would work but I have to try it out.

Comment: okay so I read the unity howto bumpmap. I get what its doing and that's what I want. except for the bumpiness. it said to make the bumps more noticeable use the bumpiness slider but instead of using the bumpiness slider couldn't I use the image to tell where the bumps should be?         so step 1 would be make a make a height map. mine would be generated from blender of the high poly mesh. then step 2 would be to generate the normal map with the bumps using the bumpiness slider. instead of using the slider couldn't I use my texture?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert your color map to a normal map and then assigning 2 normal maps in your texture slots. Then you will have to create a new image and bake the normals (not from multires). This way you have your 2 normal maps combined in 1.

-Bert