# How to unwrap an already textured model and then re project UV data

Tags: uv, topology

I am using computer software to generate a scan of a person.  The software returns a good looking mesh and a very high-polygon model.

Unfortunately the UV map is a very complex mess of image data shoved together.  It does map very well to the model, but I am hoping to unwrap the model (or re-unwrap) in a sensical way so that I can touch up the map and make minor changes (or just have a template to share with people who can easily see the cutouts of a person).

Right now I am unable to do this because the UV image data is all over the place (see images).
[image]

[image]

I am also aware that there may need to be some retopologizing done as well - I assume the typical process here is to re-topo the model and then unwrap it / bake the texture but I have never done this and am not sure how to go about this.

To be clear the ideal thing would be to be able to unwrap "UV Islands", with their current textures, in effect re-creating the UV map.

So, how to:

Create my own custom UV islands through unwrapping?

and

Have those islands keep the texture from the original model?

Can someone help me with this process? Thanks

Comment: [This](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50650/2217) is your first step.

Comment: @Carlo this looks good.  I am going to attempt it - if it is a duplicate question this should be closed.

Comment: No, I retracted the vote, it was not covering the whole problem but only a little part of it (and if you have to retopo your mesh, it would'n have worked straight). My fault. Anyway I'll leave here as a related question: [Possible to bake texture to new UV map?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15510/possible-to-bake-texture-to-new-uv-map)

Comment: Here's a question covering part about baking from an object to another: [How does normal baking work?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-does-normal-baking-work/2472#2472)