# How can I bake a normal map so that my vert count stays low?

Tags: normals

I've been trying to bake normals for window frames and door frames. I have been angling each face to make it an angle but my normals are still so sloppy looking and very undefined.  I've watched tutorial over tutorial and cannot get nice clean results...

So my question is..

HOW in the WORLD can I make a nice clean normal map for windows so that my vert count stays low enough for a mobile game yet detailed enough to make the illusion of the shapes.

If anyone has any tips and suggestions for making normals of this type please give me some lessons! am very new to modeling in general and know fairly basics of blender... Thanks.

IF anyone can make an example for me, then explain how to achieve that, it would be most appreciated.

first image is ones I baked practicing on planes.. and second is their normals

Edit: Really stressing me out lol. I was told no depth only angles but the first images from "practice" that are better than actual buidling.. are depth basically..I don't rememeber setting angles..I baked the building model same as I did the model of only windows.

if there are any tricks I am more than willing!

then on my actual "building" is the last two.. first image is high res model..
second image is the baked normals to low

Final image, low vert model

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show screenshot of the result you'd like to get with normal map (it can be high-poly original meshes) and result you get with normal map. As of now it's hard to tell what is this question about. Maybe look at [baking normal maps](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2466/how-does-normal-baking-work) question.

Comment: Okay so here's the scenario.. pictures added above

Comment: On the first screenshot the windows are as different objects (I assume those are as a reference for you). On your screenshot windows are part of the wall. What do you select when baking ? To make normal baking to low-poly work you have to have 2 (or more) objects - high-poly and low-poly to bake to.

Comment: For the baking I have a low vert model with the same outline as the high vert model. I'll show those as well above. Do certain shaders, lighting or anything effect the outcome?

Comment: Neither lighting nor shaders and staff affect baking normals, it's only geometry related. Are objects to be baked positioned one atop of another ? Also in your bake settings try increasing Distance and Bias, they control how far can the high-poly faces be positioned regarding to low-poly ones.